# Почему в начале сказок иногда используют союз А, а не И

Tags: союзы

Вот примеры сказочных зачинов:

*На поляне стояла избушка, **а в избушке жил старик**.*

*В одном государстве жил царь, **а у него была дочка красавица**.*

Можно ли здесь использовать союз ***И***? Какая разница между этими союзами?

**[Материал из Интернета](https://mydocx.ru/9-28237.html):**  Присоединительное значение сочинительных союзов.

*Встала **перед глазами** изба голодная, а в избе голодной мать хворая лежит.* (Неверов.) (Союз а, по логическому значению приближающийся к союзу и, присоединяет **добавочную** мысль, вызванную **в сознании** вставшей перед глазами **картиной избы**.)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149636/discussion-on-question-by-sharon--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.